# Aks : whitelist external Ips

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

i have deployed my application in aks and used ingress to expose the services externally , but i need to restrict the access to my application to some IPs , i ready something about whitelist Ips, i tried add my ip in my ingress like this:
[image]

but when acces the app from my machine i got 403 forbidden , so i guess that i'm not using the right Ip adress.
So what ip should i put exactly in the ingress.

Comment: I fixed this by adding --set controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local to the instll command of the ingress , but is it a good practice to limit the acces by ip adress what if the ip adress changes ? is there any other way to do this

Comment: I imagine you need to add some NSG rules on your ASK subnet.

Comment: When you found a solution it is a good practise here to answer the question yourself.

Comment: > but is it a good practice to limit the acces by ip adress 
It depends what you want to do. If you want to make your apps only be used by specific users it would be better to use authentication.

Comment: @derkoe yes i think to whitelist ip adress is a good solution for now , i'll add the solution in new answer thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by adding --set controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local to the install command of the ingress.

Comment: Correct, if you don't include that `externalTrafficPolicy`, the originating IP the ingress controller sees will be the node IP, and since that is not in your whitelist annotation, you will get a 403. `externalTrafficPolicy=Local` will preserve the originating IP so your whitelisting can take appropriate actions